# inline spacing within the `cases` command when document is in doublespace mode

Tags: spacing, cases

For journal submissions, we obviously have to use doublespace mode. But I don't want to take up even more of the page using a multi-branch cases command, which by default puts double spaces between each branch.      Obviously one can manually reduce the gap between branches with `\\[-xpt]` at the end of each branch, but it's incredibly kludgy and fragile and messes up the space between the current line and the following one.    I'm wondering if there's a package or a nice macro that would shrink the gaps in a robust way *and* manage the vertical height of the left brace.      Here's an MWE where the default spacing within the cases command is ridiculous.    Thanks!

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\lipsum[1]
$x = 
\begin{cases} 
a & \text{if } x < -3 \\
b & \text{if } -2 < x < 0 \\
c & \text{if } 0 < x < 2 \\
d & \text{if } x > 2 
\end{cases}
$
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a version that redefines the `cases` environment to temporarily switch to single line spacing within the environment. The extra definition of `\new@setfontsize` is only necessary to suppress a warning about setting text commands in math mode; it's otherwise the same as the original definition.

This pattern should be easily adaptable for other math environments, if necessary.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\new@setfontsize[3]{%
    \ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \let \@currsize #1\fi \fontsize {#2}{#3}\selectfont
}
\let\orig@setfontsize\@setfontsize
\let\orig@cases\cases
\let\endorig@cases\endcases

\renewenvironment{cases}{%
    \let\@setfontsize\new@setfontsize
    \setstretch{\setspace@singlespace}%
    \let\setfontsize\orig@setfontsize
    \orig@cases
}{%
    \endorig@cases
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\lipsum[1]
$x = 
\begin{cases} 
a & \text{if } x < -3 \\
b & \text{if } -2 < x < 0 \\
c & \text{if } 0 < x < 2 \\
d & \text{if } x > 2 
\end{cases}
$
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, I can't  tell you how long I've been waiting for this!!!!     Thanks so much tho i know I'm not allowed to say thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by setting `\baselinestretch` back to `1` inside the definition of the `cases` environment. This is a multiplier for the distance between lines in a paragraph (and also between the rows of the `cases` environment) and it was set to `1.667` by `\doublespacing`.

To patch `cases`, you can add the following snippet to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{cases}{\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont}
```

---

#### Demonstration

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %% <- added
\AtBeginEnvironment{cases}{\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont} %% <- added

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\lipsum[1]
$x = 
\begin{cases} 
a & \text{if $x < -3$} \\
b & \text{if $-2 < x < 0$} \\
c & \text{if $0 < x < 2$} \\
d & \text{if $x > 2$}
\end{cases}
$
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

Notes:

- The change to `\baselinestretch` only takes effect after `\selectfont` is called, which is why that command is there.
- Simply putting  `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont` inside the `cases` environment doesn't work because its scope will be limited to just the first cell of the environment.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than redefining `cases` to use `\singlespacing` or `\setstretch{1}`, I believe it's better to correctly set the `\arraystretch`.

Something similar should probably also be done for `array`, but one can use `\fixarraystretch{<factor>}` everywhere.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xfp,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}
  {\def\arraystretch{1.2}}
  {\fixarraystretch{1.2}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\fixarraystretch}[1]{%
  \edef\arraystretch{\fpeval{#1/(\baselinestretch)}}%
}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\lipsum[1]
$x = 
\begin{cases} 
a & \text{if } x < -3 \\
b & \text{if } -2 < x < 0 \\
c & \text{if } 0 < x < 2 \\
d & \text{if } x > 2 
\end{cases}
$
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just a final comment: using double spacing for submissions is a relic of the past; nowadays everybody receives PDF files and leaving space for annotations makes little sense; it just hinders reading the document on the screen.

Comment: Hi egreg, what's the advantage of your approach with respect to `\AtBeginEnvironment{cases}{\setstretch{1}}`?Thanks.

Comment: @CarLaTeX That it doesn't depend on `setspace`.

Comment: OK, thanks, but if I have already `setspace` loaded, does it make any difference?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes: `\setstretch{1}` does a wealth of useless things. And I wouldn't recommend the currently accepted answer, which has the same defect, only made worse. Besides, `\renewenvironment{cases}` is not the best, as `amsmath` has an indirect way to define `cases`, in order to catch foreign syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation